# hotfile uploader

Tags: file-upload

i want to write a cli program that uploads files to hotfile.com and returns the download links what is the best language to write it in and can anybody give me some hints how to send the file?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could write it in any language which could to make HTTP requests, as C# or Java. Like most websites interactions, that language will need to support some kind of `CookieContainer` in order to keep your session cookie after a web login, and to fake a POST with your file content. [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) can help you to understand how to send that information.

As this isn't a technical problem, you should first to ask if you can do that to site support personal, to do not break any TOS clause.